# Pound symbol comes in camel message as?

Tags: apache-camel

I am facing issue with Pound symbol coming in my messages to camel route , 
The pound symbol when comes in json request on my camel rest endpoint , it gets converted to "?" the same gets shown on log too.

I have tried below ways to fix this by setting convertBodyTo tag charset to utf-8 but it didn't worked.

Camel version used is 2.10. 
Locale is : en_US.

Here is the route :

`<from uri="jetty:http://localhost:8080/testService"/>

  <camel:convertBodyTo type="String" charset="utf-8"  />
  <camel:log message="Message Body: ${body}" />
  <to uri="jetty:http://localhost:8080/testEndpoints"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know the encoding the client uses when POSTing the JSON. The browser should send you the encoding information in the `Content-Type` header field.

If the Pound sign shows as a single question mark, that indicates that the stream has a single-byte encoding. If it is multi-byte and then read with a single byte encoding it would show up as two garbage characters, not one. If the Content-Type header does not specify the encoding, then try setting the western single byte encoding `ISO-8859-1` instead of `UTF-8` and see if that works. As your locale is en_US the default encoding is probably `US-ASCII`.

Comment: It's indeed correct the encoding scheme of the system wasn't UTF hence the issue , when the same request is sent with setting UTF encoding and changing the pound,euro sign with their utf code , the pound sign and euro sign are properly detect and shown on the camel side.